# Chart Id is same as a JavaScript variable name error using Fusion Chart in ASP

Tags: asp.net, fusioncharts

I have multiple charts in one page but I am getting this error when I run it:

```
 Chart Id is same as a JavaScript variable name. Variable naming error. Please use unique name for chart JS variable, chart-id and container id.
```

If I keep only one chart then it is happy.  How can I fix this? here is my code:

```
public string CreateChart()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        string sqlStatement = "SELECT Category, AvgNumbers FROM MyTable";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string strXML;
        strXML = "<graph caption='Summary' subCaption='By Category' decimalPrecision='0' showNames='1' numberSuffix=' Units' pieSliceDepth='30' formatNumberScale='0'>";
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            strXML += "<set name='" + reader["Category"].ToString() + "' value='" + reader["AvgNumbers"].ToString() + "' />";
        }
        strXML += "</graph>";
       return FusionCharts.RenderChart("/FusionCharts/Pie3D.swf", "ChartID", strXML, "FactorySum", "650", "450", false, false);

    }

    protected string CreateChart_2()
    {


        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        string sqlStatement = "SELECT count (ID)as ID, cat_name FROM MainTable group by cat_name";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string strXML1;
        strXML1 = "<graph caption='Summary' subCaption='By Cat' decimalPrecision='0' showNames='1' numberSuffix=' Units' pieSliceDepth='30' formatNumberScale='0'>";
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            strXML1 += "<set name='" + reader["cat_name"].ToString() + "' value='" + reader["ID"].ToString() + "' />";
        }
        strXML1 += "</graph>";
        return FusionCharts.RenderChart("/FusionCharts/Pie3D.swf", "MyChartID", strXML1, "FactorySum", "650", "450", false, false);
    }
```

### ASPX code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
   <div>
       <% =CreateChart() %>
   </div>
   <div>
       <% =CreateChart_2() %>
   </div>
</asp:Content>
```

I have tried everything but no solution found so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in your case 4th parameter in `FusionCharts.RenderChart` is a Chart ID and not the 2nd one. Try to vary it, e.g. "FactorySum1" and "FactorySum2" and the error should disappear.